# YouTube Autocomplete Search Api not Working

Tags: reactjs, youtube

I am trying to fetch search results by using YouTube autocomplete API but I am getting an error:

```
const YOUTUBE_SEARCH_API = http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?client=firefox&ds=yt&q=
const getSearchSuggetsions = async (text) => {
  const data = await fetch(YOUTUBE_SEARCH_API + text);
  const json = await data.json();
  console.log(json)
}
```

> ERROR
> Access to fetch at http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?client=firefox&ds=yt&q= from origin http://localhost:3000 has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

And when I write {mode: 'no-cors'} then I get a response in the network tab but don't get the result in the console, there was an error that 'Unexpected end of input'.

Answer (score 0):

The `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is something that needs to be set on the server and not on the client. Since you do not control the server, there are two options:

1. Search for another api that allows you to do a request from anywhere.
2. You can write your own backend as a wrapper (for example http://localhost:4000/api/search), that takes the parameters, fetches the data using the api and returns the data.

Answer (score 0):

The error happens because of origin policy for security reasons. To solve this issue, you can either setup your own backend or an alternative way is to use the YouTube data API which requires an API key and allows you to make requests from your frontend code.
Here's the steps you need to take:

1. Get an API Key:
   If your project is created on [Google Cloud Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/), select it, otherwise Create a new one. Then enable the YouTube Data API for your project and create credentials for the API and choose "API key." This will generate an API key that you'll use to authenticate your requests.
2. Construct the API Request:
   The base URL for the YouTube Data API is https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search. You'll need to pass your API key and the necessary parameters to the API endpoint. The main parameter you'll use is 'q', which is the search query.
3. Make the Request:
   Make a (fetch) request to the API endpoint with the constructed URL.

Once you have the response data as JSON, you can access the search results and process them as needed in your application.

Here's an example:

```js
const YOUTUBE_SEARCH_API = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search";
const API_KEY = "YOUR_YOUTUBE_API_KEY";

const getSearchSuggestions = async (text) => {
  const params = new URLSearchParams({
    key: API_KEY,
    q: text,
  });

  const url = `${YOUTUBE_SEARCH_API}?${params}`;

  const response = await fetch(url);
  const data = await response.json();

  // Process and use the data
  console.log(data);
  // You can access items like data.items, which contains search results
};

getSearchSuggestions("your search query");
```

Remember to replace "YOUR_YOUTUBE_API_KEY" with the API key you obtained from the Google Cloud Console.

Comment: Yes, I am using the YouTube data API key to fetch video data from YouTube API but in YouTube autocomplete API where to add that API key? can you please elaborate more?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I've edited the answer and added an example. Let me know if you have any further issues.